# filling multiple dataframe columns based on condition in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column for 'id' and an individual column for each day of the week.

I'm trying to fill the day columns using a condition on the 'id' column.

So for example,

```
if df['id'] == 1:
    df['monday'] = 1
```

That's all simple enough, but I have issues on one condition where I need to fill multiple columns at the same time, i.e.:

```
multiple_days = ['m', 't', 'w', 'T', 'f']

if df['id'] == 3:

for day in multiple_days:
    df[day] = 1
```

I'm obviously a beginner in Python and I can find an inefficient brute force solution, but I know there must be an easier way to do this. Can anyone help a newbie out?

Comment: Try `df.loc[df.id==1, ['m', 't', 'w', 'T', 'f']] = 1

Comment: Thanks, that's what my original solution was except I had one line for each day. Didn't know you could pass a list of days to .loc, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':[1,2,1,2,1,1],
         'm':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         't':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'w':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'T':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'f':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
})

multiple_days = ['m', 't', 'w', 'T', 'f']

m = df['id'] == 1
df[multiple_days] = df[multiple_days].mask(m, 1, axis=1)
print (df)
   id  m  t  w  T  f
0   1  1  1  1  1  1
1   2  5  8  3  3  3
2   1  1  1  1  1  1
3   2  5  4  7  9  7
4   1  1  1  1  1  1
5   1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Another idea from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775887/filling-multiple-dataframe-columns-based-on-condition-in-another-column#comment92473661_52775887) of @Pankaj Joshi:

```
df.loc[m, multiple_days] = 1
```

Or numpy solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and broadcasting:

```
arr = df[multiple_days].values
df[multiple_days] = np.where(m[:, None], 1, arr)
print (df)
   id  m  t  w  T  f
0   1  1  1  1  1  1
1   2  5  8  3  3  3
2   1  1  1  1  1  1
3   2  5  4  7  9  7
4   1  1  1  1  1  1
5   1  1  1  1  1  1
```